# Magento PayPal IPN postback failure

Tags: magento, paypal-ipn

Already since late June, PayPal IPN suddenly didn't work properly anymore.
Orders are stuck in "pending payment" status. There seems to be a problem with IPN postback:

```html
    [postback] => (postback string)
    [postback_to] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
    [postback_result] => HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/?IPN=true
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 07:37:52 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: akavpau_ppsd=1532072872~id=e027bf488669ad4f4699d81b5c8269bb; Domain=www.paypal.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000


    [exception] => PayPal IPN postback failure. See paypal_unknown_ipn.log for details.
    [__pid] => 25117
```

I noted the "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect" response. Could this indicate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal changed their callback URI: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/

From now on you must use:

```
https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```